# Increase row with indirect formula using ranges

Tags: excel, range, row

I want to be able to cut and paste the following formula across my excel table and have it update the row (no column). So `E6:AZ6` would become `E7:AZ7` on the row below, the rest would stay the same.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(FirstYears&"!$E6:$AZ6"),"X",INDIRECT(FirstYears&"!$E$1:$AZ$1"),Weeks))
```

I didn't realise (until lots of searching) that this didn't happen automatically with indirect `functions`. Doh!

I've found lots of possible solutions and I think the row function might help but as I don't know what I'm doing and none of those solutions have been with a range rather than a single cell I have been unable to work out where to put the row command, how to split the current formula and what I need to do about all that crazy punctuation...!

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Are `FirstYears` and `Weeks` named ranges? Is your problem just getting the `INDIRECT(FirstYears&"!$E6:$AZ6)` to "behave" as you would like it to? Have you tried using the `ROW()` function in conjunction with the `OFFSET()` function?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the same issue without the named ranges. Where would you put the row function in the formula? That may be all I need, I just can't work out how to write it in for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(FirstYears&"!$E"&ROW($E6)&":$AZ"&ROW($E6)),"X",INDIRECT(FirstYears&"!$E$1:$AZ$1"),Weeks))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: YES! Thank you so much Domenic! It worked and did exactly what I needed it to! Thank you!! I can now also look at how you did it so I can better understand how to combine the functions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I shall assume that `FirstYears` contains the name (as text) of a worksheet and that you want to analyse the individual rows of that worksheet, with the results contained in a second worksheet.

An alternative to using the snippet `INDIRECT(FirstYears&!"$E6:$AZ6")` in a formula in the second worksheet is

`OFFSET(INDIRECT(FirstYears&"!E6:AZ6"),ROW(cell)-n,0)`

where `cell` is the relative address of the **first** results cell in the second worksheet and `n` is a constant equal to the vale of `ROW(cell)`.

So if the first results cell is cell `A2` the formula snippet to use in cell `A2` is

`OFFSET(INDIRECT(FirstYears&"!E6:AZ6"),ROW(A2)-2,0)`

When a formula containing this snippet is copied down the results column it will deliver references to `E6:AZ6`, `E7:AZ7`, `EZ:AZ8`, etc from the target worksheet into the successive results cells (ie `A2`, `A3`, `A4`, etc) as you require.

How does it work?

`OFFSET(r,i,j)` delivers a range which is the same shape as range r but which is shifted in the worksheet by i rows (down if i is positive, up if i is negative) and j columns (to right if j is positive and to left if j is negative). 0 is a valid value for both i and j.

In the suggested formula, r is always set to range `E6:AZ6` in the target worksheet through the use of the `INDIRECT` function, i successively takes values of 0,1,2,... down the results column, and j is always set to zero. i takes values of 0,1,2,etc because the snippet `ROW(A2)-2` in cell `A2` becomes `ROW(A3)-2`, `ROW(A4)-2`, etc when copied down the results column.

Note, unlike functions such as `SUM()`, there is no problem with using a code snippet such `ROW(A2)` in cell `A2` - it does not yield a Circular Reference warning and a result of zero, instead it yields the correct value of 2.